# ASP.NET Multiple Select ListBox with CheckBoxes in a MultiView Control using jQuery and Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, listbox, asp.net-ajax

I have been trying to implement a multiple select dropdown list available at [here](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Multiple-Select-MultiSelect-DropDownList-with-CheckBoxes-in-ASPNet-using-jQuery.aspx).

However, my situation is slightly different than the example as the listbox is in an `ASP.NET` VIEW control, where this view is not loaded initially.

I noticed that the dropdown list works fine when I directly set `SampleView2` as active view in the page load. However if I load `SampleView2` later on click on button event, List box is not populated properly. Check boxes are missing.

I believe that’s because the JavaScript is not fired when `SampleView2` is loaded during the post back?  Can anyone please advise how to achieve this?

Here’s my code.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Bootstrap_MultiSelect_DropDown.WebForm1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('[id*=lstFruits]').multiselect({
                    includeSelectAllOption: true
                });
            });
        </script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:MultiView ID="MultiViewMain" runat="server">
<asp:View ID="ViewSampleView1" runat="server">
<p>SampleView1</p>
<asp:Button ID="ButtonLoadSampleView2" runat="server" Text="LoadSampleView2" 
        onclick="ButtonLoadSampleView2_Click" />
</asp:View>
<asp:View ID="ViewSampleView2" runat="server">
<div>
<p>SampleView2</p>
<asp:ListBox ID="lstFruits" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Mango" Value="1" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Apple" Value="2" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Banana" Value="3" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Guava" Value="4" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Orange" Value="5" />
</asp:ListBox>
</div>
</asp:View>
</asp:MultiView>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
</body>
</html>


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace Bootstrap_MultiSelect_DropDown
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                MultiViewMain.SetActiveView(ViewSampleView1);
            }
        }

        protected void ButtonLoadSampleView2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MultiViewMain.SetActiveView(ViewSampleView2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Update : As I couldn't figure this out I had to implement the functionality using CheckBoxList control.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run client side code after server side. So you can use

***.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!IsPostBack)
   {
       MultiViewMain.SetActiveView(ViewSampleView1);
   }            
}

protected void ButtonLoadSampleView2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      MultiViewMain.SetActiveView(ViewSampleView2);
      //Line to add so that you can access client script from server side 
      //where getView is a function on client side
      ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(Page), "alertScript", "getView();", true);
}
```

***.js**

```
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
    function getView() {
        $('#<%= lstFruits.ClientID %>').multiselect({ includeSelectAllOption: true });
    }
</script>
```

***.html**

```
<ContentTemplate>
            <asp:MultiView ID="MultiViewMain" runat="server">
                <asp:View ID="ViewSampleView1" runat="server">
                    <p>SampleView1</p>
                    <asp:Button ID="ButtonLoadSampleView2" runat="server" Text="LoadSampleView2" OnClick="ButtonLoadSampleView2_Click" />

                </asp:View>
                <asp:View ID="ViewSampleView2" runat="server">
                    <div>
                        <p>SampleView2</p>
                        <asp:ListBox ID="lstFruits" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Mango" Value="1" />
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Apple" Value="2" />
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Banana" Value="3" />
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Guava" Value="4" />
                            <asp:ListItem Text="Orange" Value="5" />
                        </asp:ListBox>
                    </div>
                </asp:View>
            </asp:MultiView>
        </ContentTemplate>
```